# Find multiple occurances in string

Tags: javascript

If I have the below string, how can I search through it and return an object with a key represented by {{ key }} and the value set to the word tacked on to it, as in, **not!** a space in between.

I dont understand how I would look for each occurance in a string thats starts with {{ ...has some name... and ends with }}  as its not always going to be called one two three four as in the example below.

Example:

```
"The quick {{one}}onyx goblin {{two}}jumps over the {{three}}lazy {{four}} dwarf"

obj={
  one:"onyx",
  two:"jumps",
  three:"lazy",
  four:NULL
}
```

Note that {{four}} is NULL because its a **space before** the word dwarf. The word dward is not directly tacked on to {{four}}

grateful for any help,
thank you.

Comment: What if `{{one}}` occurs multiple times?

Comment: doesnt matter.... lets say, store the first occurance and ignore if it shows again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to locate the braced properties in the input string and their value. Then use `Object.fromEntries` to turn those key,value pairs into an object. Note that this will take the *last* value if a property occurs more than once in the string.

```js
const parse = (str) =>
    Object.fromEntries(Array.from(str.matchAll(/\{\{(\w+)}}(\S*)/g), arr => 
        [arr[1], arr[2] || null]));

// demo
let s = "The quick {{one}}onyx goblin {{two}}jumps over the {{three}}lazy {{four}} dwarf";
let result = parse(s);
console.log(result);
```

If you don't have support for `matchAll`, then:

```js
const parse = (str) => {
    let regex = /\{\{(\w+)}}(\S*)/g;
    let match;
    let result = {};
    while (match = regex.exec(str)) {
        result[match[1]] = match[2] || null;
    }
    return result;
}
// demo
let s = "The quick {{one}}onyx goblin {{two}}jumps over the {{three}}lazy {{four}} dwarf";
let result = parse(s);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: thank you. but what if i dont know the name of the props, but first have to look for them in the string. anything within {{  ... }}

Comment: Added a solution for when you want any property in the string.

Comment: second solution is what im looking for, but im getting an error when testing it on jsbin, "str.matchAll is not a function" : https://jsbin.com/miyaliduwo/edit?js,console

Comment: It is part of current version of JavaScript, EcmaScript 2020. Which version do you support?

Comment: Added a version that doesn't use `matchAll`.

Comment: i wouldnt be able to aswer that exactly, but 202 is a bit too fresh for this. but say i would prefer ES5. edit: thanks for added version.

Comment: Using the last version, if the word after braces is a negative number, it does not get added to the object. exmple: {{two}}-1

Comment: What is your requirement for the character that may follow the closing braces? Should a comma be picked up? A slash, a plus, ...etc, ...etc. Can you explain the rule? I updated the answer so it will pick up anything that is not white space.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227730/discussion-between-jason-and-trincot).

Answer (score 2):

You can also proceed in the following way:

```
    let a = (x) =>{
    let obj = {};
    let z = x.split(' ');
     let m = z.filter(x1 => x1.charAt(0) == '{')
    m.forEach(x2=> obj[x2.substr(2,x2.indexOf('}')-2)] = x2.substr(x2.lastIndexOf('}')+1) == '' ? null : x2.substr(x2.lastIndexOf('}')+1))
    console.log(obj);
    
}

a("The quick {{one}}onyx goblin {{two}}jumps over the {{three}}lazy {{four}} dwarf")
```

This might solve your query.

Answer (score 2):

This will work

```
const str = "The quick {{one}}onyx goblin {{two}}jumps over the {{three}}lazy {{four}} dwarf";
const result = {}

str.split("{{")
    .map(m => ({
        [m.split('}}')[0]]: m.includes("}}")
            && (m.split('}}')[1].split(' ')[0] || null)
    })).filter(e => e[Object.keys(e)[0]] != false).forEach(e => { result[Object.keys(e)[0]] = Object.values(e)[0] })
console.log("result", result)
```

Answer (score 1):

This example is a bit verbose, but meets the need for variable names within the `{{}}`.

This code is a bit verbose, but allows one to read and understand:

```js
const str = "The quick {{one}}onyx goblin {{two}}jumps over the {{three}}lazy {{four}} dwarf";

let output = str.match(/({{\w*}}\w*\b|{{\w*}} )/g).map(sub=>{
   const subArr = sub.replace('{{','').split('}}');
   const o = new Object();
   o[subArr[0]] = subArr[1];
   return o;
});

console.log(output);
```